# TimeOut for WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

i was wondering how to implement a TimeOut for: **WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication** ?

When to use: 
Show an error on the watch if the background operation on the iOS app takes to long.

Comment: Dunno if this is good or not. But fire a timer and tick it (increase an Int every second and when it hits x show a message) or when you gets a response just invalidate the timer. But it feels like this is something the SDK/FrameWork should handle.

Answer (score 0):

`openParentApplication:reply:` returns an `NSError` if the request fails. I would suggest a better method would be to indicate to your user that a request is in progress and respond appropriately when it finishes. If you app's functionality is so brittle that you need to show an error for a long-running task, you may want to reconsider how you're accomplishing this task.